# unmarshalling <br/> in XML data

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have some xml data I'm trying to unmarshall into java objects and one of the elements contains `<br/>` elements:

```
<details>
    <para>
        Line Number One
        <br/>
        Line Number Two
    </para>
</details>
```

In my Details java object I have:

```
class Details {
    @XmlElement(name="para")
    private List<String> paragraphs;
}
```

The problem is that the only element in the paragraphs list is 'Line Number Two'. Does anyone know how I can deal with this?

Comment: Both answers currently given are good, but which one applies depends on what `<br/>` should be. Do you want it as a piece of text, or as an actual element? In the latter case, follow avtaxt's answer. In the former case, it should be in a CDATA section or using character entities (like `&lt;br/&gt;`) as Vivek said.

Comment: My preference would be for the `<br/>` to be text but unfortunately the xml is generated by someone else so it seems axtavt's answer is the one to go with at the moment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can represent mixed content with [`@XmlMixed`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlMixed.html) as follows (note that it's applied to content of a class itself rather than to its element, thus you need an additional class):

```
class Details {
    @XmlElement(name="para")
    private Para para;
    ...
}

class Para {
    @XmlMixed
    @XmlAnyElement
    private List<Object> paragraphs;
    ...
}
```

`paragraphs` property will contain `String`s for text lines and `Element`s for XML elements.

Answer (score 2):

In that case the XML is not formed correctly. Put the entire data inside the  tags within CDATA to avoid this issue. Refer - http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: Why? It looks valid. `<br/>` is correct thing for xml. The question is how to map it with jaxb

Comment: In the current context, "<br/>" is a part of the <para> tag.

Comment: You're both right, but looking at the `paragraphs` declaration of the asker I think he does intend to get `<br/>` as text.

Comment: @kan - When i say malformed, i am not speaking of the syntax. If you analyze the context here, "<br/>" is data part of <para> tag and not a tag on its own containing data within it. Since "<br/>" should be treated as data and not a tag, it must be provided within CDATA.

Comment: If he is allowed to change the structure, it's better to separate text by tags, than including markup in CDATA blocks: `<para>
        <line>Line Number One</line>
        <line>Line Number Two</line>
    </para>`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@XmlAnyElement` along with a `DomHandler` to preserve fragments of the XML document as a `String`.  Below is a link to a complete example demonstrating how to do this:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html